# open pdf after generate pdfkit/node webkit

Tags: javascript, node-webkit, pdfkit

I am working on a cross-platform App with Nw.js. 
I am trying to genrate PDF and to get it open but it dont work ! and i have no errors !

```
    var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
    var fs = require('fs'); 
    var appContent = document.getElementsByClassName('response');
    doc = new PDFDocument;
    doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.pdf'));
    doc.fontSize(15);
    doc.text(appContent[0].innerHTML);
    doc.end();
```

Do you have any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: `and to get it open` how are you trying to do that?

Comment: Open or saved ! i only get an object with console.log(doc) :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is automatically saved in a Temp folder.
just call:

```
 window.open('output.pdf');
```

And that's it